# How do I link math library to my compiler in codeblocks?

Tags: c

[image: Screen shot of the build log]

It seems that it is not able to locate math library.
While compiling this program gives an error:

```
undefined reference to'pow'
```

I am completely clueless about this.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int number1, temp, number2 = 0, x, count = 0;
    printf ("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number1);

    x = number1;
    while (number1 > 0)
    {
        temp = number1 % 10;
        number2 = (number2 + temp)*pow(10, count++);
        number1 = number1/10;
    }

    printf("The original number order was: %d\n", x);
    printf("\n");

    printf("The reverse number order is: %d\n", number2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you link against the math library? (`-lm`)

Comment: ceil(double) not integer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link math library while compiling your program like this:

```
gcc test.c -lm
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525675/why-does-math-h-need-to-be-linked-in-makefile-but-not-string-h?noredirect=1) is a good explanation why is it necessary for <math.h>.

Comment: How do i get to terminal where I can compile like: gcc test.c -lm ?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The terminal is in Ubuntu's application list. You can also type Ctrl-Alt-T to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I am able to run the terminal and get the O/p.

Answer (score 4):

You add "libm.a" to your "Link libraries" if you're using the GNU GCC Compiler in a Debian based Linux environment.

1. Click on "Project"
2. Click "Build options.."
3. Click the "Linker settings" tab
4. Click the "Add" button inder the "Link libraries"
5. Type in "libm.a" and click "OK"
6. Click "OK" again (this time on the "Project build options" window)

And make sure you have #include <math.h>

Comment: Why do you use libm.a ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

1. Click on "Settings",
2. Click on "Compiler",
3. Click on "Linker settings" tab,
4. Click on "Add",
5. Type "libm.a" and "OK",
6. Click on "OK" and
   that's all.

You're ready lo link against math library on linux using gcc (Don't forget "#include <math.h>" in your source code).